# Tiny library just for Blob Storage on Windows Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

The [Windows Azure Storage](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage) package comes with a truckload of dependencies, including improbable libraries such as [System.Spatial](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Spatial/). I only intend to use the Blob Storage, which should represent about 5% of this package. Is there any *stand-alone* library available to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could always make direct REST API calls, as the storage API is [well-documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179355.aspx). This is about as lightweight as you're going to get. There is no other official .net Azure SDK other than the one you referenced. I don't know of any 3rd-party .net SDKs available.

Comment: Isn't there a truckload of classes for accessing the storage in the Azure SDK?